# Using raw-loader to load animations in Angular 2

Tags: angular, webpack

I've been using this pattern for a while now:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'foo',
    template: require('./foo.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./foo.component.scss'),
    animations: [ //some twenty or thirty lines of code might be here ]
)}
```

Webpack handles these nicely with `{ test: /\.(css|scss|html)$/, use: 'raw-loader' },`

I tried something new today. I moved my animations (everything in the []) to a separate file and named it, e.g., *foo.component.animations*. What follows seems pretty self explanatory to me:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'foo',
    template: require('./foo.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./foo.component.scss'),
    animations: [require('./foo.component.animations')]
)}
```

And in webpack:

```
{ test: /\.(css|scss|html|animations)$/, use: 'raw-loader' }
```

It should find my **.animations* file and drop the text right into `animations: []`, right?

But all I get are complaints from the compiler.

Has anyone else moved their animations out of the component file?

**[Edit]**

Here is the complaint:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at View_SidebarComponent_0 (/AppModule/SidebarComponent/component.ngfactory.js:71:5)
    [angular]
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste the complain you're talking about? It could help us find the issue.

Comment: I added the complaint.